# Is `operator new` a part of C++ core language?

Tags: c++, new-operator

I have been told that "new-expression will call `operator new` to manage dynamic storage and initialize the object at the same time" many times. And I don't doubt about that. But I'm wondering that since `operator new` is declared in standard library header `<new>`, how could we still using new-expression even if we include no header files.

Is `operator new` a part of C++ core language or the compiler includes `<new>` implicitly?

Comment: It's good to remember that `operator new` names a function, and in fact names a set of overloads. Nothing unusual about that. It also means that not all overloads may come from the same source. That's the problem with your statement that "`operator new` comes from `<new>`" - it only covers some overloads, not all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes `operator new` is part of the standard.  The implementation is required to supply the operator at the global scope in each translation unit in your program.  From [basic.stc.dynamic]/2

> The library provides default definitions for the global allocation and deallocation functions. Some global allocation and deallocation functions are replaceable (18.6.1). A C++ program shall provide at most one definition of a replaceable allocation or deallocation function. Any such function definition replaces the default version provided in the library (17.6.4.6). **The following allocation and deallocation functions (18.6) are implicitly declared in global scope in each translation unit of a program.**
>
> ```
> void* operator new(std::size_t);
> void* operator new[](std::size_t);
> void operator delete(void*);
> void operator delete[](void*);
> void operator delete(void*, std::size_t) noexcept;
> void operator delete[](void*, std::size_t) noexcept;
> ```

<sup>emphasis mine</sup>

This is why you do not need to include anything to use `new`/`new[]` and `delete`/`delete[]`.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, `operator new` is part of the C++ standard.

See [[expr.new]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.new).

Most of `#include <new>` is [implicitly declared](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.stc.dynamic#2). But `#include <new>` declares some more versions of `operator new`, which are not implicit, for example *placement new**:

```
void* operator new  (std::size_t size, void* ptr) noexcept;
void* operator new[](std::size_t size, void* ptr) noexcept;
```

* *placement new* is not recommended for daily use.

Answer (score 2):

I agree, this tends to be confusing, but there are a lot of news in C++ (pun intended):

1. One of them is the "`new` operator"
2. Another one is "operator `new`" a function doing the actual memory allocation
3. There is placement `new`
4. and some might not like the name, but there is also array `new`s (`new[]`)

Not considering 3, 4 because they are worth a post of their own ([What uses are there for "placement new"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222557/what-uses-are-there-for-placement-new)  and [How do I use arrays in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c)), the first one ("`new` operator") resides in the global namespace, and it is accessible with the the scope-resolution operator (`::`), and the second one is the one you can overload in your classes. However regarding the relation of these two, there is an excellent explanation in MSDN (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kewsb8ba.aspx) I just paste it here:

> The new operator invokes the function operator new. For arrays of any type, and for objects that are not of class, struct, or union types, a global function, ::operator new, is called to allocate storage. Class-type objects can define their own operator new static member function on a per-class basis.
>   When the compiler encounters the new operator to allocate an object of type type, it issues a call to type::operator new( sizeof( type ) ) or, if no user-defined operator new is defined, ::operator new( sizeof( type ) ). Therefore, the new operator can allocate the correct amount of memory for the object.

Answer (score 0):

The header only provides declarations for all variants of the global `operator new`. You can still override them without including the header, as long as you get the operator signature right.

Answer (score 0):

The default allocation and deallocation functions are special components of the standard library; They have the following unique properties:

> **Global:** All three versions of operator new are declared in the global namespace, not within the std namespace.
>   **Implicit:** The allocating versions ((1) and (2)) are implicitly declared in every translation unit of a C++ program, no matter whether header  is included or not.
>   **Replaceable:** The allocating versions ((1) and (2)) are also replaceable: A program may provide its own definition that replaces the one provided by default to produce the result described above, or can overload it for specific types.

Source: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20new/